# Подключиться по TCP при помощи сайта и DNS записи SRV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, dns

Использую Cloudflare для сокрытия IP сайта, хочется сделать тоже самое для сокрытия IP для TCP сервера.
Имеется подключение Client -> Server -> Client напрямую через IP и порт.
Хочу реализовать подключение, используя DNS запись SRV на C++.
Есть идеи? Может быть есть статьи на эту тему, самостоятельно искал в интернете - не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно именно под винду, то в Windns.h есть функция `DnsQuery`, умеет получать записи SRV (`DNS_TYPE_SRV`)
Можно взять за основу [пример](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/831226/how-to-use-the-dnsquery-function-to-resolve-host-names-and-host-addres). У меня заработал частично - получить ip адрес (SRV возвращает имя всегда) не удалось (подозреваю, проблема в кодировке, не разбирался)
https://gist.github.com/krepver/b2cab8d939fb36d9dd9e23dd9bcd2648

```
dnsTest.exe -n _jabber._tcp.jabber.ru -t SRV -s 8.8.8.8
Address: jabber.ru
Port: 5269
Failed to query the host record for jabber.ru and the error is 123
```